# Why doesn't sign (appear to) change in inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given the equation $\frac{1}{x}\gt -1$, I would assume one would work it as
$$\frac{1}{x}\gt-1$$
$$x\cdot\frac{1}{x}\gt-1\cdot x$$
$$1 \gt -x$$
$$-1\cdot 1 \gt -x \cdot -1$$
$$-1 \lt x $$
which is incorrect, because the answers should be $x\gt0$ or $x\lt-1$. When I put the correct answers in, it makes sense, but I can't see how to get them algebraically. Is there some rule that I'm missing or misusing?

Comment: The reason is that when you multiplied both sides by $x$ in the second inequality, you assumed that $x > 0$. The way you can see this is that if $x < 0$, the inequality would switch directions. So really what you have is that $-1 < x$ and $0 < x$ (for part of the solution) which says that $0 < x$. Can you see how to get the other part of the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that when you multiply an inequality by a negative number, you reverse the direction of the inequality. Thus,

$$x\cdot\frac1x>-1\cdot x$$

is true only if $x>0$. If $x<0$ you’re multiplying the original inequality by a negative number, and you get

$$x\cdot\frac1x<-1\cdot x\;.$$

Thus, you actually end up with two cases:

$$x>0\quad\text{and}\quad x\cdot\frac1x>-1\cdot x\tag{1}$$

and

$$x<0\quad\text{and}\quad x\cdot\frac1x<-1\cdot x\;.\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ simplifies to $x>0$ and $1>-x$ and thence to $x>0$ and $-1<x$; $x>0$ already implies that $x>-1$, so this case gives you the solutions $x>0$.

$(2)$ simplifies to $x<0$ and $1<-x$ and thence to $x<0$ and $-1>x$; $x<-1$ already implies that $x<0$, so this case gives you the solutions $x<-1$.